# Android SQLite: Loading spinner dynamicaly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've tried out a couple different ways of loading the spinner from SQLite database, this method seems to be the simplest and easiest. The only thing is since i have added in a couple of my own variables (three more). When I run the edited version to fit my testing needs everything runs correctly except the spinner doesn't fill with data from the database

[image]

### SpinnerLoad Class

```
public class SpinnerLoad extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Db thisTestDBAdapter;
    Button save;
    EditText one, two, three;
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinnerform);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_save);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_serial);
        two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_name);
        three = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_place);
        fillData();
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_spinner);
        try {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Person());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Person implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        static String personReturn;
        static boolean personTest = false;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> x, View y, int z, long w) {
            personReturn = (x.getItemAtPosition(z)).toString();
            personTest = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            personTest = false;
        }
    }

    private void fillData() {
        try {
            Cursor coloursCursor;
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_spinner);
            coloursCursor = thisTestDBAdapter.fetchAllColours();
            startManagingCursor(coloursCursor);

            String[] from = new String[] { thisTestDBAdapter.KEY_TWO };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvDBViewRow };

            SimpleCursorAdapter colourAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.db_view_row, coloursCursor, from, to);

            spinner.setAdapter(colourAdapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinLoad_save:
            String bx = two.getText().toString();
            /**/
            String ax = one.getText().toString();
            String cx = three.getText().toString();
            String returned = Person.personReturn;

            Db entry = new Db(this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(ax, bx, cx, returned);
            entry.close();

            fillData();
            /**/
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Db SQL helper class

```
public class Db {

    private static final String TAG = "SpinnerDBHelper";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private final Context mCtx;
    /**/
    private static final String KEY_DB = "DataBaseName";
    private static final String KEY_TABLE = "DbTable";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_rowid"; // 0
    public static final String KEY_ONE = "serial";
    public static final String KEY_TWO = "name";
    public static final String KEY_THREE = "place";
    public static final String KEY_FOUR = "returned";
    /**/

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE DbTable (_rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "serial TEXT NOT NULL, "+ "name TEXT NOT NULL, " + "place TEXT NOT NULL, " + "returned TEXT NOT NULL);";  

    public Db(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public Db open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String ax, String bx, String cx, String returned) {
        if (mDb == null) {
            this.open();
        }

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ONE, ax);
        cv.put(KEY_TWO,  bx);
        cv.put(KEY_THREE,  cx);
        cv.put(KEY_FOUR, returned);

        return mDb.insert(KEY_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public boolean deleteEntry(long rowId) {
        return mDb.delete(KEY_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public boolean deleteAll() {
        if (mDb == null) {
            this.open();
        }

        return mDb.delete(KEY_TABLE, null, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllColours() {
        if (mDb == null) {
            this.open();
        }

        return mDb.query(KEY_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TWO},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, KEY_DB, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KEY_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

### LOGCAT

> ```
> 12-26 23:39:33.409: W/System.err(30879): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-26 23:39:33.409: W/System.err(30879):    at com.my.examples.SpinnerLoad.fillData(SpinnerLoad.java:59)
> 12-26 23:39:33.409: W/System.err(30879):    at com.my.examples.SpinnerLoad.onCreate(SpinnerLoad.java:30)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 12-26 23:39:33.418: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 12-26 23:39:33.428: W/System.err(30879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 12-26 23:39:33.428: W/System.err(30879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 12-26 23:39:33.428: W/System.err(30879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 12-26 23:39:33.428: W/System.err(30879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 12-26 23:39:33.428: W/System.err(30879):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879): Error inserting place=zyxwvutsr returned=null serial=123456789 name=abcdefghij
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at com.my.examples.Db.createEntry(Db.java:56)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at com.my.examples.SpinnerLoad.onClick(SpinnerLoad.java:86)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 12-26 23:40:00.628: W/System.err(30879): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at com.my.examples.SpinnerLoad.fillData(SpinnerLoad.java:59)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at com.my.examples.SpinnerLoad.onClick(SpinnerLoad.java:89)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 12-26 23:40:00.639: W/System.err(30879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 12-26 23:40:00.649: W/System.err(30879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 12-26 23:40:00.649: W/System.err(30879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 12-26 23:40:00.649: W/System.err(30879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 12-26 23:40:00.649: W/System.err(30879):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

With the log cat, I can do just about the beginner Newbie stuff lol .. but I have looked it over a couple times and side by side with the original and not sure what i might have messed up. Hoping someone might be able to shed little light on this for me, if any more info is needed please let me know. Thanks

Comment: After taking the extra reference out, still having the same issue,,, tried fixing the sql error `12-26 23:40:00.628: E/Database(30879): Error inserting place=zyxwvutsr returned=null serial=123456789 name=abcdefghij` i set the "returned" variable to String returned = "someText" and it still errors out.. hope'n when i get off work today and mess around with it a bit more maybe i'll find out whats causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are referencing *Spinner* two times

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_spinner);
```

here

```
fillData();
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_spinner);
....
```

and here

```
 private void fillData() {
        try {
            Cursor coloursCursor;
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLoad_spinner);
....
```

Comment: ahh forgot to delete it when i moved it to filldata();